# connection "developer" is not defined

Tags: magento2, database, ssh

Anytime I run this to install any extension:
**php bin/magento setup:upgrade.**
I get the error -

> **connection "developer"  is not defined.**

I have tried to change the mode to developer and when I run it, the same issue comes out. this has reduced my ability to install new apps.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found a way out..
i went to the app/etc/local.xml

and changed the connection to default and mode to default..

worked out well for me

Comment: You may mark your answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Answer (score 5):

After taking pull from git for a running projec, I forgot to put env.php in app/etc dir, and I faced same issue.
Check if env.php is there and set the connection for default_setup is "default or developer" as per you deploy mode.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem when I tried to install Magento in production mode. So I switched to developer mode, installed Magento and than switched to production and this helped. Magento version is 2.4.3

Answer (score 1):

env.php 
just changed 'connection' => 'default'

Fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

As i have checked in env.php there was issue under 
  'resource' => [
        'default_setup' => [
            'connection' => 'default'
        ]
    ],

Connection was developer.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the env.php file exists in the app/etc folder. If it's there, check whether the values present are correct or not